Density of Schwartz distributions in the space of distribution
Let $S(R^3)$ and $D(R^3 )$ be the space of  Schwartz function and test function respectively, $S'(R^3)$ and $D'(R^3)$ be their duals.
I want to understand what "$S'(R^3)\subset D'(R^3)$ and the inclusion is dense" means.
$S'(R^3)$ is a space of distributions so obviously $S'(R^3)\subset D'(R^3).$
Now we focus on the density. Let $\langle \bullet, \bullet \rangle$ denote the duality breached.
Question: Does “$S'(R^3)$ dense in $D'(R^3)$” mean : $\forall T \in D'(R^3) \ \exists T_n$ a sequence in $S'(R^3)$ such that $\forall \psi \in D(R^3)$ we have $\langle T_n , \psi\rangle \to \langle T, \psi \rangle$?
